# InternalError: GPU sync failed in Google Colab

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, scikit-learn, keras

While trying to tune the ANN model using GridSearchCV, I faced the following error in Google Colab. Can anyone help me on this or have faced any similar issue like this?

```
def build_classifier(optimizer):
    classifier = Sequential()
    classifier.add(Dense(units = 6, kernel_initializer = 'uniform', activation = 'relu', input_dim = 11))
    classifier.add(Dense(units = 6, kernel_initializer = 'uniform', activation = 'relu'))
    classifier.add(Dense(units = 1, kernel_initializer = 'uniform', activation = 'sigmoid'))
    classifier.compile(optimizer = optimizer, loss = 'binary_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])
    return classifier
classifier = KerasClassifier(build_fn = build_classifier)
parameters = {'batch_size': [25, 32],
              'epochs': [100, 500],
              'optimizer': ['adam', 'rmsprop']}
grid_search = GridSearchCV(estimator = classifier,
                           param_grid = parameters,
                           scoring = 'accuracy',
                           cv = 10)
grid_search = grid_search.fit(X_train, y_train)
best_parameters = grid_search.best_params_
best_accuracy = grid_search.best_score_
```

### **Error:**

```
Epoch 1/100

InternalError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in _do_call(self, fn, *args)
   1360     try:
-> 1361       return fn(*args)
   1362     except errors.OpError as e:

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in _run_fn(session, feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list, options, run_metadata)
   1339           return tf_session.TF_Run(session, options, feed_dict, fetch_list,
-> 1340                                    target_list, status, run_metadata)
   1341 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/errors_impl.py in __exit__(self, type_arg, value_arg, traceback_arg)
    515             compat.as_text(c_api.TF_Message(self.status.status)),
--> 516             c_api.TF_GetCode(self.status.status))
    517     # Delete the underlying status object from memory otherwise it stays alive

InternalError: GPU sync failed
```

Comment: Is this error reproducible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to limit the amount of used memory. It will slow down the training but that's what fixed that for me..

```
config = tf.ConfigProto()
config.gpu_options.per_process_gpu_memory_fraction = 0.3
set_session(tf.Session(config=config))
```

Comment: If you still getting this error try to reduce your batch size.

Answer (score -1):

Try to change the runtime type from 'GPU' to 'None'. This will probably give you a different error that is more useful!

Comment: Different error needn't always be a step in the right direction. With deep neural nets you would always prefer to use GPU. If not for GPU, there is very limited advantage of running the code on colab as compared to your local machine.